Shipping binary asset and loading it in Dart
I have package my_package that is a dart wrapper package for a binary.
At the moment this binary loaded using
DynamicLibrary loadDll(String name) {
  final String debugAssetsDir = normalize(join(Directory.current.path, 'assets'));
  final String releaseAssetsDir = normalize(join('data', 'flutter_assets', 'assets'));

  final String packageAssetsDirPath = normalize(join(File(Platform.resolvedExecutable).parent.path, releaseAssetsDir));

  String dllDir;
  try {
    dllDir = normalize(join(debugAssetsDir, name));
    DynamicLibrary library = DynamicLibrary.open(dllDir);
    return library;
  } catch (e) {
    dllDir = normalize(join(packageAssetsDirPath, name));
    DynamicLibrary library = DynamicLibrary.open(dllDir);
    return library;
  }
}

I am referencing my_package via a git dependency, but this doesn't work since my_package doesn't share/copy its asset directory into referencing project. What is the right way of referencing this binary in my_package so that I can load the library in my_package for unit tests as well as in referencing projects?
